# Java EE 6 Compliant Request Based Framework

Tags: frameworks, components, request

recently, i was research about which framework to learn.

I realize that request based component is mostly used in industry and has its own advantages because of its scalability. Moreover, there are some forumer that mentioned learning of component based framework(Standard Java API/framework/JSF) is waste of time(Is this true ?). On the other hand, customization in component is quite difficult but require to write less code.

My Question :

1. Which request based framework is compliant to Java EE 6 ?
2. Do ejb exclude from spring ot strut ?
3. Which framework has higher level and yet powerful and flexbility, performance ?
4. How to create UI in spring ? There are some people who used struts for front end and spring for back end or use spring alone.
5. Is correct to say that there is no HttpServlet anymore and instead of replace by action or something else.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would go es neat to java standard as possible, so look at ejb3/jpa for persistence and jsf2 for front end.

in a jee6 environment you can completely forget everything about struts and spring...

and of course there is still a HttpServlet, most of the web front end technologies are based on Java Servlet Specification.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I realize that from job advertisement in industry which used spring or struts. Moreover, strut and spring is implement according JSR but with extra functionality.

Comment: The standard is specify the life cycle of application.

Comment: I hope someone can enlighten me. Thanks.